# Nativescript Google login plugin

Tags: google-signin, nativescript

Is there a google login plugin for nativescript. I tried to search to [npm](http://www.npmjs.com) but there's only google sdk and google maps. I want to add a google login for my nativescript project. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have answer about this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only social login plugin that exists at present is for Facebook.

Comment: Yes. that's what Im seeing on npm. So currently, there's only facebook login plugin for nativescript :(

Comment: There is a growing community of plugin developers though, so I'm sure something will crop up soon. In the meantime head over to the Nativescript forum to keep an eye out, you can find the link on nativescript.org

Comment: Could you either accept the answer or close the question please?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific plugin for this, however, the [Microsoft Azure Plugin](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-azure-mobile-apps) has Social Sign-in support for Google, Facebook, Microsoft and Twitter. However, of-course you would need to be using an Azure Backend. There also seems to be a [Firebase Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase), but I am not familiar with it.

Otherwise, plugins are a really good way to become familiar with the underlying Nativescript platform and aren't too hard to write your self.